# Access child on a table using Xpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am trying to access a specific element of the Dom using XPath

Here is an example

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>1</b> <a href="http://www.url.html">data</a><br>
            <b>2</b> <a href="http://www.url.html">data</a><br>
            <b>3</b> <a href="http://www.url.html">data</a><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to target "table td" so my query in Xpath is something like

```
$finder->query('//table/td');
```

only this doesn't return the td as its a sub child and direct access would be done using

```
$finder->query('//tr/td');
```

Is there a better way to write the query which would allow me to use something like the first example ignoring the elements in-between and return the TD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a better way to write the query which would allow me to use
>   something like the first example ignoring the elements in-between and
>   return the TD?

You *can* write:

```
//table//td
```

**However, is this really "better"?**

In many cases the evaluation of the XPath *pseudo-operator* `//` can result in significant inefficiency as it causes the whole subtree rooted in the context-node to be traversed.

**Whenever the path to the wanted nodes is statically known, it may be more efficient to replace any `//` with the specific, known path**, thus avoiding the complete subtree traversal.

**For the provided XML document, such expression is**:

```
/*/*/tr/td
```

If there is more than one `table` element, each a child of the top element and we want to select only the `td`s of the forst `table`, a good, specific expression is:

```
/*/table[1]/*/tr/td
```

**If we want to select only the first `td` of the first `table` in the same document**, a good way to do this would be:

```
(/*/table[1]/*/tr//td)[1]
```

**Or if we want to select the first `td` in the XML document** (not knowing its structure in advance), then we could specify this:

```
(//td)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a thorough breakdown of ways to target the elements!

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy oh boy, there's something not seen often.
 As for your first xpath query, you can just return what you want but use double // on before tagnames

But, I don't see why you don't just want to get the td's by tagname...

Comment: I guess I should have made it clear why I was doing it this way - I am parsing a css file and then targeting elements based on the css query. I am also trying to target other elems such as "a img {}"

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is:

```
$finder->query('//table//td');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this way too:-

```
$finder->query('//td');
```